# Binding popup to Leaflet.js circle : NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I am using leaflet and trying to create a popup over a circle I have created. I am using the following code

```
    var jsonString = '{"location":"edinburgh","topNouns":["track","love"],"eventWords":{"shot":1},"numberOfTweets":177.0,"numberOfTweetsContainEventWord":1.0,"percentageOfEventTweets":0.5649717514124294,"lat":55.953252,"lon":-3.188267}';

    var json = JSON.parse(jsonString);     

    var text = json.lat;
    alert(text);
            var circleColor = 'red';
            var circle = L.circle([55.953252, -3.188267], 9000, {
                color: circleColor,
                fillColor: circleColor,
                fillOpacity: 0.5
            })
                .bindPopup(text)
                .addTo(map);
```

The code reads in the JSON string, creates a circle then attempts to bind a popup to the circle.

No pop up appears however and I get the following error

```
Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8
```

I believe this is occurring when I pass the text variable into the .bindPopup method. When I insert a constant text value into the .bindPopup method the popup displays correctly however I want it to get the text from the JSON.

Using the alert method I was able to see that the variable text is being retrieved from the JSON correctly.

Does anyone know why this error is occurring?

Link to JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8HLJn/1/

Struggling to get the map showing within JSFiddle however.

Comment: Can you post an example somwhere like http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: Created a jsfiddle but its for somereason not showing in the result. Included all the external scripts, not sure what is wrong. http://jsfiddle.net/z2J86/1/

Comment: Your jsonSource won't work, because the fiddle isn't running on your server.  You're better off copying some sample JSON directly into the example and using that.  I cleaned some things up in this fork: http://jsfiddle.net/8HLJn/

Comment: Having troubles getting the page to display in JSFiddle as I use an external JSON file to load in data

Comment: Thanks, will add some sample data

Comment: Still having problems with the JSFiddle unfortunately. Sorry about this. Completely new to web development

Comment: My problem on fiddle is reading in the JSON as previously it was read in via a file

Comment: Just copy the contents of the Json file into the fiddle and assign it to a variable. Json is just a JavaScript object after all

Comment: @elevine The way I was parsing the JSON doesn't seem to work when I simply store it in a variable.

Comment: You don't have to parse it, the json is already a JavaScript object.  Please update your question with the latest code and describe exactly what is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to fix the problem. I needed to convert the text variable to a string as follows

```
.bindPopup(String(text))
```

Not entirely sure why the alert method showed the text correctly whereas I had to cast the variable to a string for it to display in a leaflet popup.